# SSH Install Mysqlnd - Package Not Found

Tags: ssh, mysqlnd

I am trying to install Mysqlnd using ssh and the `yum` command but I keep getting the error that no such package exists. Can someone help me out? I have also tried `yum search php-mysqlnd` and there is no such package on the system.

Comment: `yum list|grep -i mysql` will tell you what packages have 'mysql' in the name.

Comment: Still nothing called mysqlnd.

Comment: then it's not available from your distribution's repo.

Comment: So then how would i get it from my distribution repo (whatever that is).  I am a newbie and just simply trying to get mysqlnd installed on my server.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you'll have to pull it from another repo, I suggest Atomic's repo.

They have a simple one liner auto installer, give it a shot.

`wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh`

Then of course `yum update` and then fire off `yum install php-mysqlnd`

Edit: Sounds like you've got some yum excludes active.

`vi /etc/yum.conf` and you'll likely see something to the effect of `exclude=mysql* php*`. You can comment out this line or just remove them altogether.

Another options is to use the command line option...

`yum --disableexcludes=all` which will kill all excludes currently active.

`yum --disableexcludes=main` which will kill all excludes in your main yum.conf.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that but got the same results after following your instructions.  No package found when i run yum install php-mysqlnd

Comment: I am already running php5.4 and from what i can find mysqlnd should already be  part of it.  Im not even sure if im running ssh correctly or looking in the right place to download it.

Comment: Are you jailed? Try `sudo yum install php-mysqlnd`

Comment: Still getting response " Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www6.atomicorp.com
 * base: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * extras: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * updates: p3plmirror02.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Well that narrows it down, your yum configuration is excluding mysql packages or possibly just php-mysqlnd. You can edit the exclusions in `/etc/yum.repos.d` but beware it's probably excluded for a good reason. Php-mysql is likely installed and it conflicts with php-mysqlnd.

Comment: Yes it does.  Everythign i have read says you have to uninstall php-mysql first then install php-mymsqlnd after.  But even when i do yum remove php-mysql it says there is no such package.  I don't know how to make edits to a director.  I guess ill do some more google searching.  Going on 4 hours trying to fix this, thank you for your help.

Comment: Do `vi /etc/yum.conf` and you'll likely see something near the bottom like this `exclude=mysql* php*` Hey gotta take off for a bit but can help when I get back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48830/discussion-between-user982853-and-d3c0y)